# PHP preg_match an html arttribue with number seprated by a comma

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to get the values of an attribute and fill them in an array:

```
<p numbers="11.2,1.1 2,3,3.1 33"></p>

preg_match('/numbers="([0-9\\.]]+)"/',$elements,$match);
```

I need something like this:

```
$match[0] -> 11.2
$match[1] -> 1.1
$match[2] -> 2
```

Or anything that would get me to store the numbers in an array, but I can't figure out the regex for it.

Comment: start use your right string you use points but in your string we seen numbers...

Comment: ya thanks I fixed it

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got one solution:

```
$string = '<tag> etc</tag>
<p numbers="11.2,1.1 2,3,3.1 33"></p>
<div> etc</div>';

// Catch only the numerals from the attribute numbers
preg_match('/<p.*numbers="(.*)"/', $string, $match);

// Catch each number separated by comma or space.
preg_match_all('/(\d+(\.?|\s?)(\d+)?)/', $match[0], $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
```

The regex is somehow pretty straightforward, but if you need some clarification, write a comment.

And you can see it tested here: https://3v4l.org/iVp1v

Comment: well I have other elements as well, Im searching for the element with the numbers attribute

Comment: Like I said, you can combine both solutions. I'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would simply match all numbers and then split them

```
$matches = preg_match('/numbers="(.*)"/',$elements,$match);
$numbers = explode(',', $matches[1]);
```

Comment: I still have the whitespace issue. Meaning numbers are either separated by comma or by whitespace(s).

Comment: But in that case they are bound for a conflict... can't you decide for one or another?

Comment: Well you can simply parse the array again (if array then loop it and explode by space)

Comment: No I cant, but how about replacing all whitespaces with commas? excpet i need to replace multiple whitespaces with on comma. ex 1,2   (too many or one whitepsace)    3 should be 1,2,3

Comment: I think I got it. Though I would also prefer to use this one and explode, you can even combine both solutions.

Comment: $matches = preg_replace('/\s+/', ',', $matches);

Comment: your first line should be preg_match('/numbers="(.*)"/',$elements,$matches); and not $matches = preg_match('/numbers="(.*)"/',$elements,$match);